# Style all open captions at once in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, cc-2017

Is it possible to style all open captions at once in Premiere Pro CC2017?

Since Adobe promotes the captions feature as a way to edit all captions in one place, I hope there actually is a way to style them all at once.

Comment: Any update on this - is it still not possible?

Answer (score 1):

This has changed in the 2017 release of Premiere CC. You can now change all captions at once. Plus Adobe has added some other enhancements to the caption workflow.

Comment: Ho do you change all captions at once in the 2017 release of Premiere CC?

Comment: You can no longer select all captions in 2021, unless you do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the captions in the Captions window; then go to the top right are of the window, right above the first caption -- here, you'll find a grid made up of 9 little squares. Select the bottom middle and all of your subtitles will align in the center of the frame. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As of Premiere 2021 you don't need to select all captions to change the style for the whole project. Just change the style for a single caption, and hit the "Push to Track or Style" button. All other clips in that style will take on those settings.
[image: Push to track]

If you have the option, push to style works just fine. I've had some trouble with push to all captions.
[image: Push style attributes]

Answer (score 0):

If you select all the captions in the Captions window (not the timeline) you can change the font parameters there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Right-click on the blank space of any caption and you'll see a "select all" option. Congratulations, you are now a Jedi that can edit everything at once. Enjoy.

Comment: This doesn't work in Premiere 2021

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately no, and sadly there is not even an option to 'select all.'

I believe you can export the captions and load it into a program like Lemony to do you styling (better option anyways), and then import a alpha-channel file back in to Premiere (more on that below).

---

I have recently (about 2 months ago) started getting into subtilting or open captions for projects. And as of now I can say that I am very disappointed in Premiere's captioning system. If you are just doing 2-3 sentences its fine, otherwise I use a dedicated system for it.

My workflow is as follows

1. [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) to create a encore txt file
2. Import in [Lemony Subtitler](http://www.lemonysubtitler.com/)
3. Run a batch style on all my subtitles
4. Export .avi? with alpha channel
5. Import into Premiere and put the subtitles on a top layer.

This workflow is extremely fast, and way better than dealing with Premiere's archaic captioning system. Especially Aegisub, which uses some wizardry to automagically select spoken 'text' by analyzing the waveform so that your subtitles meet an optimal length (characters per second) for reading based on the time of the selection.